# Angular 2 angular-ide Component is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template

Tags: angular

I work with Angular 2 and I use Angular-ide.

I have the following component

[image]

In this component I get the error

```
Component 'AppComponent' is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule
```

I tried

```
npm install @angular/language-service
```

but this didn't fix the error.

Model is

```
export  class Model {
    user;
    items;

    constructor(){
        this.user = "Adam";
        this.items = [new TodoItem("Buy Flowers", false),
                      new TodoItem("Get Shoes", false),
                      new TodoItem("Collect Tickets", false),
                      new TodoItem("Call Joe", false)]
    }

}

export class TodoItem{
    action;
    done;

    constructor(action, done) {
        this.action = action;
        this.done = done;
    }
}
```

In the project' structure I don't have module.js, only module.ts

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I don't have AppComponent within any app.module

Comment: then that's the problem...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to a module in order to use the component, ie:

```
@NgModule({
...
declarations : [ AppComponent ]
...
})
export class MyModule
```

Also add the necessary imports (omitted in this example)

The error message even says to add it to a module:

> Consider adding it to a NgModule